# pipe node streams in parallel with highland js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

I have an array of async node streams that I want to consume in parallel is there a easy way to do this in highland js? I'm trying to have all these arrays go through an aggregation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to do something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
const nodeStreams = [request('http://www.example.com'),
                     request('http://www.example1.com')];

hl(nodeStreams)
.map(hl)
.merge()
.map(JSON.parse)
.each(console.log);
```

I'll explain what's going on here. You start with an array of Node streams and you use `map` to convert them into Highland streams so you now have a stream of streams. The `merge` function then merges all the values into a single stream. All those streams will be read in parallel but `map(JSON.parse)` will only be called on them one at a time. If you want to paralellise more of the computation then you want to do as much with each of the streams before you call `merge`:

```
hl(nodeStreams)
.map(stream => hl(stream).map(JSON.parse))
.merge().each(console.log);
```

If the order of the requests matters then you should use `parallel` but this incurs a performance overhead because the function has to keep track of all the different streams.

Comment: Similar scenario, but instead of reading files I'm trying to consume multiple http requests (hundred or so) and then piping them down to a json parser to extract fields.

Comment: Cool. The principle is exactly the same so I've update the answer to work with http requests instead.